# How can I make Squeak ask me where to fileOut to?

Tags: squeak

I'm right-clicking a class category and choose fileOut for exporting it to an .st file. The problem is that it never asks me where to save to, instead just choosing a folder by itself (seems to be the same folder containing the image file).

How can I change it, forcing it to actually ask me where to save the file to? Previous Squeak versions (3.9.x) did ask me.

Squeak version is 4.2, OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like if you don't mind filing out twice, the default behaviour in 4.3 is to prompt if you would overwrite an existing file. Something like `Class.st already exists`, then select `choose another name` and you can write to the correct place in any directory, albeit with a second copy in the directory with the image.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked in Pharo and it's the same, the menus just offer to file out to a predefined location.

However, it's still perfectly possible to trigger a file out by script. Look for implementors of `#fileOut` and `#fileOutOn:` for examples; evaluating something along the lines of `myProgramEntity fileOutOn: aFileStream' should do it.